# ipad object scrollbar

Tags: webkit, overflow

first timer here.  I help manage a WordPress site that has an html object imbedded in a div that overflows.  The scrollbar functionality works fine on pc's; however, on an ipad (and I assume an iphone and android devices), the scrollbar doesn't appear.  The html I have is:

```
#wrapper {
width:100%;
height:360px;
overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}

#wrapper object {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

<div id="wrapper">
<object id="object" type="text/html" data="[link to html page with lots of <tr> rows]"
</object>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if perhaps the webkit overflow attribute should be on the object instead of the div to get this to work correctly?